Comparing faces in a single image using AWSRekognition
I'm familiar with comparing faces and determining similarity using 2 images. What I was curious about is if there is a way to detect two faces in one image which can be calculated for similarity. As an example, consider a US driver license, where many states embed a smaller image of the driver.
I've not be able to use the CompareFaces command without using two separate images
